# postgres - how to choose last transactions per user_id, per transaction type?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have the following table (raw_data):

```
trans_id,user_id,msg_code,record_time
```

given a time frame (from_time,to_time) i would like to query:
get for each user:
get the last msg_code of each type.

more explanation:
would like to receive for each user, 
unique msg_code, so that each such row is the last(record_time wise) per user

table example (trans_id,user_id,msg_code,record_time):

```
1, 1, 100, 2013-06-03 08:32:51
2, 1, 100, 2013-06-03 09:32:51
3, 1, 101, 2013-06-03 08:32:51
4, 1, 102, 2013-06-03 10:32:51
5, 2, 100, 2013-06-03 06:32:51
6, 2, 100, 2013-06-03 07:32:51
7, 2, 100, 2013-06-03 08:32:51
```

outcome example:

```
2, 1, 100, 2013-06-03 09:32:51
3, 1, 101, 2013-06-03 08:32:51
4, 1, 102, 2013-06-03 10:32:51
7, 2, 100, 2013-06-03 08:32:51
```

futile attempt (not working..):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id,msg_code)
       *
FROM  raw_data
ORDER BY user_id, msg_code ASC
```

- if anything is unclear pls ask.

thanks for your help!

Comment: You say that you want the latest record per user, per transaction type - how is transaction type to be derived?

Comment: thanks for your help, im sorry for wasting your time i find the solution.

Comment: "Not working" as in "not working as expected" or "resulting in an error"? (It is never a bad idea to clarify the "not working" bit *every time*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out i was only missing a small part:

this is working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id,msg_code)
       *
FROM  raw_data
WHERE record_time > '2013-05-28 17:06:01' and record_time < '2013-05-30 17:06:01'
ORDER BY user_id, msg_code ASC, record_time DESC
```